# Fixed table header have an empty space on its right side

Tags: css, html-table

I have a fixed table header. problem is on top of the scroll bar there is empty space and the `thead` does not cover this part.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table {
  background-color: transparent;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
table thead {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span5">      
  <table class="table table-fixed table-hover" id="CAGraph_table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th class="sht col-xs-3">Date</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">2G</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">3G</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">4G</th><th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G</th><th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G/4G</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.61</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.62</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.54</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.54</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.77</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.55</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.58</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.67</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.18</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.43</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.46</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 23:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 22:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.22</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 21:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 20:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 19:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 18:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 17:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 16:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 15:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.12</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.74</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 14:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.99</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.53</td><td class="col-xs-2">99</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.05</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 13:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.55</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.02</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.82</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.86</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.9</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.73</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.83</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.74</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.84</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.25</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.83</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.82</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.79</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 23:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 22:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 21:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 20:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.84</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 19:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 18:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 17:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.87</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 16:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 15:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 14:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.12</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 13:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.61</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.1</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.08</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.11</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.2</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.57</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.2</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.93</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr></tbody>
      </table>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `padding-right` and your columns should be good to go.

```
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table {
  background-color: transparent;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
table thead {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span5">      
  <table class="table table-fixed table-hover" id="CAGraph_table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th class="sht col-xs-3">Date</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">2G</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">3G</th><th class="sht col-xs-1">4G</th><th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G</th><th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G/4G</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.61</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.62</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.54</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.54</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.77</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.55</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.58</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.67</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.18</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.43</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.46</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 23:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 22:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.22</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 21:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 20:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 19:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 18:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 17:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 16:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 15:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.12</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.74</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 14:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.99</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.53</td><td class="col-xs-2">99</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.05</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 13:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.55</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.02</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.82</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.86</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.9</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.73</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.83</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.74</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.84</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.25</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.83</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.82</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.79</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 23:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 22:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 21:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 20:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.84</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 19:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 18:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 17:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.87</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 16:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 15:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 14:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.12</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 13:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.61</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.1</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 12:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.08</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 11:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.11</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.07</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 10:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.2</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.57</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.2</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 09:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 08:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 07:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 06:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.93</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 05:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 04:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 03:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 02:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 01:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr><tr><td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 00:00</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td><td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td><td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td></tr></tbody>
      </table>      
    </div>
```

Comment: Suppose the actual table is 375px but bootstrap is making it 475px. how can i reduce the table width without messing up the alignment between `thead` and `tbody` as well as keeping it responsive

Comment: @bonez That is a new question. Please accept an answer here, if any, that solved this question and post a new with the facts is requires.

Answer (score 0):

Change this -

```
.table-fixed thead {
    width: 97%;
}
```

to following -

```
.table-fixed thead {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table {
  background-color: transparent;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 100%;
}
table thead {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span5">
  <table class="table table-fixed table-hover" id="CAGraph_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sht col-xs-3">Date</th>
        <th class="sht col-xs-1">2G</th>
        <th class="sht col-xs-1">3G</th>
        <th class="sht col-xs-1">4G</th>
        <th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G</th>
        <th class="sht col-xs-2">2G/3G/4G</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 12:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.61</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.62</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.93</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 11:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.54</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.54</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.77</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 10:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.55</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.87</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.58</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.78</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 09:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.67</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 08:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.24</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 07:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 06:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 05:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 04:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 03:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 02:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 01:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.3</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.43</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-16 00:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.23</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 23:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 22:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.22</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 21:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 20:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 19:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.97</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 18:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 17:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 16:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.25</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.9</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 15:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.12</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.07</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.74</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 14:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.04</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.99</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.53</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.05</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 13:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.55</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.95</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.02</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 12:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.82</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.86</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.85</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 11:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.73</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.83</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.8</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.86</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 10:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.74</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.84</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.81</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">98.87</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 09:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.93</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.01</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 08:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.13</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.19</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 07:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.83</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 06:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 05:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 04:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 03:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 02:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.82</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 01:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.8</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.34</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-15 00:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.29</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.79</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 23:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 22:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 21:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.33</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 20:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.31</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.84</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 19:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.28</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 18:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.26</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.42</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.86</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 17:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.24</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.41</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.87</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.41</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 16:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.19</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.85</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.32</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.37</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 15:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.06</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.21</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.78</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 14:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.71</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.06</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 13:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.09</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.61</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 12:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.92</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.08</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.5</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.04</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.08</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 11:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">98.98</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.11</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.07</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 10:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.05</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.2</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.57</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.16</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 09:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.27</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.81</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.33</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.38</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 08:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.36</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 07:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.48</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 06:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.45</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.93</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 05:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 04:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.39</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.46</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 03:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.35</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 02:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.37</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.95</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 01:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.38</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.44</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">2015-12-14 00:00</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.4</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.47</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1">99.94</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.45</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2">99.5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: won't this mess up alignment with bootstrap and `col-xs-3` classes?

Comment: @bonez not sure about this

Comment: if i set to 100% the columns dont align with tbody

Comment: @bonez but I'm curious about why you use `col-` classes on a `<td>` element.

Comment: i saw an example online somewhere using bootstrap to get fixed column headings